# SDL Multithreading with variables -- Doesn't work as expected

Tags: c++, multithreading, sdl-2

I have in a namespace called *Main* an static integer, and a static class variable called *other*, like this:

```
namespace Main {
    void test();

    static Client other;
    static int v = 0;
}
```

Then, when the program starts, Main::test() is called, and creates a thread via SDL:

```
void test() {
    SDL_CreateThread(Client::test, (const char*)"Client", (void*)NULL);

    v = 1;
    std::cout << v << std::endl;
    ...
}
```

This makes the Client start a function called *test*, which prints the vector size forever, like so:

```
int Client::test(void* data)
{
    while(1) {std::cout << Main::v << std::endl; }
}
```

Now, here's the problem! *Main* returns 1 and *Client* returns a lot of zeros! What happened there? The variable is static, so it *should* be the same for *Client*!

Comment: Yes, it can, if you have errors in your code. We won't be able to tell much until you provide an [mcve].

Comment: Uhm, the number of elements in a vector *is* its `size()` by definition... what is this other number of elements you are talking about?

Comment: Let me guess: the code you're talking about does something like this: `std::vector<int> vec; vec[0] = 3;`. The size of the vector is 0, so `vec[0]` is not a valid element. Assigning to it produces undefined behavior.

Comment: Okay, added the code example. It *may* be a little off-topic, but the problem is still the vector.

Comment: No, the problem is the threading. The optimizer is allowed to be very aggressive until you tell it specifically that something might be mutated in a different thread.

Comment: My crystal ball predicts that `Main::v` is declared as `static` in a `.h` file, and `Main::test()` and `Client::test()` are implemented in separate `.cpp` files that share the `.h` file, so they end up operating on their own separate local copies of `Main::v`, where the 1st copy is populated and the 2nd copy is not.

Answer (score 3):

`std::vector.size()` is, by definition, the number of elements in the vector.

Any situation where you think that isn't the case, or you see symptoms of that not being the case, you are probably experiencing undefined behavior due to memory corruption or out-of-bounds accesses.

Note that assigning to an indexed location of a vector `v[n] = x;` does not extend the vector, and is undefined behavior if `n >= v.size()`.

Comment: It might add to the answer if you mention "reserve()... push_back()" vs "resize()" along with mentioning the various constructors which allow creating a vector of a desired size.

Answer (score 2):

Without explicit synchronization, the compiler is allowed to optimize the Client::test method by assuming that v never changes.

This is because it obviously doesn't change in that thread, it's your responsibility to tell the compiler if it could change in a different thread, and you did no such thing.

Comment: Is it possible to tell the compiler that v could change without making both threads synchronize?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a standard container in two threads, so you need to protect every access with a mutex. That creates a memory fence (which solves the problem you've seen), and protects from internal corruption when you perform actions on the container from different threads simultaneously (which your answer does not attempt to solve).